# Puppeteer - Using only 1 browser instance

Tags: puppeteer

How do I have it so when doing multiple task of puppeteer it only uses 1 browser instance? The site I am scraping rn is detecting the **creation** of browser instances even after await browser.close(). So if I always have the browser open I can get around it.

Example Scenario:

```
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true}); //

    // Have this only run once ^^^^

    // Command gets run, it should not make a new browser and instead go
    // to make a new page    
    // VVVVVVVV

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.goto(args[1]) // Go to the url the user specified

    // do some stuff

    await page.close();

   //repeat from browser.newPage();

})();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the puppeteer.connect() mentioned in another answer, here is another one.

A very easy way to do this is to create the browser only once. Initialize it only if it was not initialized before. Just ensure the browser variable is outside of whatever scope you have, if it's an express app, ensure it's outside of the route.

```js
let browser;

(async() => {
    if(!browser) browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.goto(args[1]) // Go to the url the user specified

    // do some stuff

    await page.close();

})();
```

Comment: What a neat way! This was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: I have a similar structure, but I am calling the async function from a loop. Interestingly the browser variable does not seem to update. Could that have something to do with the other iterations entering the function before the browser variable can get set?

Answer (score 2):

You can launch the browser once and then use [`puppeteer.connect()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions).

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

```js
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
      browserURL: 'http://localhost:9222',
      defaultViewport: null,
      headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(args[1]) // Go to the url the user specified

    // do some stuff

    await page.close();

    browser.disconnect();
})();
```